# Using path to load the file

Tags: java, file, path

this one thing just keeps coming back to me. I am trying to load the .csv file in Java and it looks like this:

```
public static List<String> getEntryList () throws IOException{
    final String NAME = "test.csv";
    final String PATH = "resources/csvFiles";
    final Path path  = FileSystems.getDefault().getPath(PATH, NAME);

    return Files.readAllLines(path, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
}
```

obviously not working. Gives me `java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: resources\csvFiles\test.csv` exception, but works ok when I enter tehe full path on the drive. I tried using `classpath` but also didn't work. What is the proper way of doing this?

Comment: What's the full path? How are you invoking the program? What's the current directory and what is FileSystems.getDefault() returning? Sounds like your current directory is simply not what you're assuming it will be.

Comment: I've put this file into scr/main/resources/csvTest folder and if I provide the path starting from C:\\ it works. the method you mentiones returns: sun.nio.fs.WindowsFileSystem@7ae9c52d

Comment: Right. Which means the problem is specifically with the relative path. What are you taking it relative _to_?

Comment: I fixed it. I was supposed to use src/main/resources/csvFiles instead of what I was using. Thanks for your attempts to help.

Comment: Quite likely, accessing `src/main/resources/csvFiles` will only work within your IDE, but it won't once you try to run your application in another location. If the CSVs are actually on your classpath (they seem to be), use `ClassLoader.getResource()` (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResource(java.lang.String)) instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
InputStream is = YourClassName.class.getResourceAsStream("test.csv");
```